# For loop to While loop Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

how can i change this code into **while loop**.
I'll convert it into a **while loop**

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] numbers={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        for(int x:numbers){
            if(x==30){
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(x);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just get the iterator of the array, loop as long as `hasNext()` returns `true` and get the element using `next()` in the loop. Or use an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int[] numbers = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};    
    int i = 0;                               
    while (i < numbers.length) {             //iterating till the last element in the array on index
        int currentValue = numbers[i];       //storing in a variable for reuse while printing the value
        if (currentValue == 30) {            //conditional break in the loop as OP
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(currentValue);    //printing each element in a newline
        i++;                                 //incrementing the counter to the next index
    }
```

**Output:**

```
10
20
```